# Не могу запустить openpyxl в PythonShell

Tags: python, path, openpyxl

Не могу запустить *openpyxl* в *PythonShell*

Пишу `import openpyxl`

Выдает ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import openpyxl ImportError: No module named openpyxl

В CMD прописывал:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Все ок.

Набираю слово `python`
Все ок, выдает `dthcb`.

Пишу: `import openpyxl` 
Выдает ошибку.

Как исправить? Может я путь прописал как-то не так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Набираю слово python Все ок, выдает dthcb.`
попробуйте написать `python3`

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из скриншота, у Вас в системе установлены как минимум 2 версии Python'ов (за Anacond'у не могу сказать наверняка). При этом для запуска `pip` используется 3-я версия, а для запуска `python` - 2-ая. 
В итоге - модуль openpyxl установился для Python3, а использовать Вы его пытаетесь в Python2.